# A very strange for loop bug in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to alter the attributes of an array of Buttons, however I am getting some very strange errors. I am trying to loop through the buttons to edit the height attribute of each one, however when I set up a for loop (i=0; i<3; i++), buttonSkater[i].setHeight(buttonHeight); the result seems to be that 9 buttons are being altered! And when I set i<14 (there are 14 buttons), then the application crashes with a NullPointerException.

```
package com.rollerderby.lineuptracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Setup extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.setup); 

        Button[] buttonSkater = new Button[14]; 
        buttonSkater[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater1);
        buttonSkater[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater2);
        buttonSkater[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater3);

        int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); 
        int buttonHeight = (screenHeight-60)/14; 


        for(int i=0; i<14; i++)
        {
            buttonSkater[i].setHeight(buttonHeight);
        }


    }
}
```

It seems a very strange error... Am I missing something obvious?

(Sizing the array wrong by creating it with space for new Buttons?)

Comment: Use a debugger to walk through the actions taken in the loop. You know why the code above, specifically, will throw a NPE, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based purely on your code example, you're trying to access the 3rd to 14th element in an array that has only 3 indexes set (0 to 2), the other ones are (by default) initialized to null. As for the 14 buttons, are they 14 instances of just 3 buttons perhaps?

Comment: Oh Frak. Wow, my brain has definitely gone into hibernation for Winter :P

Answer (score 3):

@fwielstra's answer is the right one, but for posterity, I thought I'd add some improvements to your code to help with resolving the problem in the future.  Instead of doing this sort of code which is prone to the sort of error you had:

```
Button[] buttonSkater = new Button[14]; 
buttonSkater[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater1);
buttonSkater[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater2);
buttonSkater[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater3);
```

Instead you can initialize the size of the array like:

```
Button[] buttonSkater = new Button[] {
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater1),
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater2),
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkater3),
};
```

And when you are processing the array, instead of doing the following which means that if you change the size of the array, you need to do it in multiple places:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    ...
```

I would use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonSkater.length; i++)
    ...
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you :) I've not used Java much in a long time and my head's still a little foggy - as I'm sure is obvious ;) - after a month of a bad cold. Improvements are always welcome :)

Comment: Sure thing man.  I've been there.  Just pointing out some better patterns for the future.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Without access to your XML, my guess is, if with a loop until 3 you're changing other 9 buttons it's because their id might be the same (i.e., copy/paste mistakes).

Also, from your code, it seems normal your application would crash with your loop until 14; after all, only the first 3 elements were instantiated. Once it gets to the 4th, it should access a null value, thus causing an error.

Comment: Their ID definitely wasn't the same, not sure what was causing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, your "14" loop is failing because only positions 0-2 have been assigned to anything.  In Java, when you do

```
 String[] strings = new String[5];
```

Nothing but the array has actually been initialized so

```
 strings[0] == null;
```

and so on until you've actually initialized those values.

You need to manually initialize each value with

```
strings[0] = new String();
strings[1] = new String();
...
```

We'll need to see the other code to answer your question about modifying nine buttons.